# test with lodash if exist property in object inside array list

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array having objects and properties.
I need to know if a string appears in property "text" in any of rows on this array. I know that this can be with .filter and .lenght but i'm looking do it with lodash

```
const myArray=
    [
    {id: 6, text: "error1", isError: true}
    {id: 7, text: "error2", isError: true}
    ]
```

Example:

lodash.contains (myArray,"error1","text") looks seems not the right syntaxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
_.some(myArray, item => item.text === "error1")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CRice noted, you can use `_.some`. Actually you do not need `lodash` for this, as there is native [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method available:

```js
const myArray = [
    {id: 6, text: "error1", isError: true},
    {id: 7, text: "error2", isError: true}
];

console.log(myArray.some(item => item.text === "error1"));
```